# What's underlying mechanism of communication between UnityWebplayer and Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I've developed a Winform software which has a UnityWebplayer module.First I try to communicate between them by socket,however,I've searched a **api** which can do this conveniently for me:

`axUnityWebPlayer1.SendMessage( "Sphere", "Down", null );//called in winform`

Just use the code snippet above then we can send message from winform to its embeded unitywebplayer module.

```
axUnityWebPlayer1_OnExternalCall_1(object sender,AxUnityWebPlayerAXLib._DUnityWebPlayerAXEvents_OnExternalCallEvent e)
```

And by using the snippet above we can receive message from unitywebplayer in winform.

I'm curious about the mechanism behind the api.Does it treat the file "*.unity3d" exported from unity3d as something like `.dll`,which makes the communication become function calling,and load it in runtime?

Comment: UnityWebplayer has been deprecated for years now.

Comment: @Programmer Really?I use that module in visual studio 2015 ,with unity 5.0.1,and it still provides a good support for unitywebplayer.By the way,what's the new method?

Comment: It was removed around 5.4v and I am sure most web browsers have already removed components required to make it work. UnityWebGL is the new way.